# How to enable AutoScrolling in FlowLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've a `FlowLayOutPanel` containing several items (e.g. some **cmd** windows). When there are more items in the panel the `ScrollBar` is not shown automatically, although they don't fit in the window.

How do I enable this automatic behavior?

Comment: The sense was not understandable at all. Anyway the question is simple, but lacks the code of the creator.

Comment: @abcccd How on earth do you put CMD windows inside a FlowLayoutPanel? (I'm gonna go write your answer now).

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know what you've got inside your FlowLayoutPanel besides cmd windows, but setting `AutoScroll` to `true` on the `FlowLayoutPanel` and setting `Wrapcontents` to `true` should cause both horizontal and vertical scrollbars to appear when they should.

If they're not, it may have something to do with the fact that you're putting other windows inside the FlowLayoutPanel. Maybe try placing each cmd window inside another panel, and place those panels inside the flow layout panel.